# Youtube .NET API v3 batch search

Tags: .net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using Google YouTube .NET API version 3. I added following nuget packages

As given in the Youtube developer example, I can do a single search for a single search query. How can I batch a few search queries in a single shot. From the developer documents I know I could execute 50 operations. (any 50 CRUD). How to do this using .NET client library?
Can you give me a code example. So far I am following this example

[Search by keyword](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet)

```
 private async Task Run()
    {
      var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
        ApiKey = "REPLACE_ME",
        ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
      });

  var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
  searchListRequest.Q = "Google"; // Replace with your search term.
  searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

  // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
  var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

  List<string> videos = new List<string>();
  List<string> channels = new List<string>();
  List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

  // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
  // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
  foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
  {
    switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
    {
      case "youtube#video":
        videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));
        break;

      case "youtube#channel":
        channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
        break;

      case "youtube#playlist":
        playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
        break;
    }
  }

  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Videos:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", videos)));
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Channels:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", channels)));
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Playlists:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
}
```